# Where to start from in my first App (the app is similar to Words With Friends)

Tags: android, database, google-app-engine, cloud, reportingservices-2005

Okay here we go.....i am developing my first app...i take through the app step by step.

Currently I have learnt all from User interface, activity, threads and services, intents, and database

I want the app to be a multiuser app, where the users can create their own accounts and log in......

The following are the areas of assistance i really want to be helped

The app is the database app that will be collecting different number entries from the users, and querying them, and finally produce reports. reports will vary depending on the user specifications. Like if he want the report to be localised, or for Africa only, or america only

Area1: I need the app to store data online. No data will be stored in the app itself. The app will produce only the user interface. once the data is sent online, all the querying will be done online, and the reports produces. The problem is i don't know how to go about this. I heard that Google drive offer this service, how can I go about using the Google Engine or any other Cloud storage. Thats the first and the most important areas of assistance

Area 2: Users communications:
When the users enter the data, he has to choose which user has to accept the data.
 Once the second user accept, then the data will be stored in the database. Hence the data will only be stored in the database,only when the second user accept the data to be valid.....

its just like when you initiate a game, and the game will be created , only when the second user, accepts the game...so the same logic
This is the second area of assistance I need

Area3: The app should have the ability to produce reports, depending on the users specifications. A user may want to see the report say, for Uganda only, or Africa only. Thats the third area of assistance

Area4: The app should also be able to produce graphs on the user performances depending on the data in the database. In short, i want to use the user's database to produce graphs....how can I got about this one....

I think that's all for now....I would really appreciate if i could get some hints on how go about this, because I fee lost not knowing where to start. Once i get to know where i can start, the journey will be much easier, because it will be well directed

Am sorry I couldn't get into specificity...you know, copyright, and all....

In short, I would like you to have a look at WWF app(Words With Friends)....Although my app is not a game app..my the ideas is exactly as the one for WWF. Multiple users, who can share scores data, and the app can query the data, and produce reports, both in graphs and the normal reports depending on what you want .....

Please guys, I know the app sounds complex, but Its what I want for my first app to be. I need guidelines to know where to start, because once you know where to start, it will be more easier to actually works hard on it.

I am the amateur programmer, so please go easy on the explanations in more simple languages

Comment: So basically, here is my idea, can someone plan this project for me?

Comment: Honestly though, I would start your VERY first app with something much simpler than this. Maybe even create an app for each item in your areas you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

**Area 1:**

You need to store data online? I would recommend the Datastore. This can be used to store data in the format of Entities that are of a certain Kind, and each Entity has Properties. You can write queries on these entities, kinds, and properties, sort of like a traditional SQL database.

You can use Google Cloud Storage to store things like images and other binary files, where you don't need to query or filter, but only retrieve.

**Area 2:**

You will probably want to write a web page that uses forms. The first user submits their form, with the various data `<input>` for their message, and also will need a dropdown menu of other users which is built from a query against the stored user profiles in your database, so that they can select the person who receives the message.

The server will receive this form submission on a POST handler (an HttpServlet doPost() method in java, or a webapp2.RequestHandler post() method in python) and store it in the database.

The second user will make a request to a certain page, say `/monitor`, and when the server serves this page, it will insert into the page the details of which messages were sent to the user that requested the page. The user can then use a form in the page to send back to the server that they want to accept this message.

**Area 3:**

Very similar to the above. You should use a string property or a repeated string property (ie. a collection) in the database Entity to mark each record as applying to a given geographical area, such as Uganda. The user can select to view reports through submitting a form that the server gets data from and redirects to serve a page.

**Area 4:**

Look into a third-party graphing library that can generate graphs on the server-side when the page request is received, or you can look into a front-end client library like [D3.](http://d3js.org/)

Comment: Please note that these are very abstract and high-level recommendations. You could use any number of different patterns to accomplish the same thing. [I think you should try to do some of the app engine tutorials to build example apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction), and see the patterns they use. After doing this, you will be ready to write WWF. Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: No worries :) best of luck with your app, and definitely check out all the docs on the cloud platform website for tutorials. [Here's a great online course that walks you through all different aspects of web development on the app engine](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud859). It's free for 14 days, which should be enough time to get through it or at least through a good portion. Again, best wishes for your coding :)